# Copy-and-paste is often corrupted

Tags: clipboard

I have ubuntu 10.10 with the 64-bit desktop version. When I copy-and-paste into any window, including firefox, terminal, java swing app, remote desktop, often I get 4 random letters (a 32-bit value?) if I try to copy again it may work this time or I might get another corrupt sequence.

This happen more often than not. I have tried to search for a solution but it doesn't appear to be a common problem.  Any suggestions on what I should try next to fix this?

It appears that copying twice helps ^C^C often works.

EDIT: I have traced the problem to using remote desktop to a tightVNC server.  When this is running the copy/paste doesn't work well. When I don't that this running there is no problem.

Comment: That's very strange!  Try using a clipboard manager to see what is happening a little better.  Parcellite is in Software Manager, and the far more comprehensive Glippy can be found on Launchpad.  I don't have an answer because I've never come across this bug, but these programs might help you diagnose the problem better.

Comment: @Deadite81, I don't have a clipboard-manager installed AFAIK, as I have only found them to cause problems in the past. I will try Parcellite to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: parcellite -c prints ²½ (plus 3 special chars not show here)

Comment: Really?  I can't live without a clipboard manager!  I can live without Ubuntu 64bit though.  I had so many problems with it I went back to 32.  Maybe it's a bug only affecting 64bit systems.

Comment: Hm.  That's beyond my expertise!

Comment: @Deadite81, mine too. Thank you for you help.

Comment: formatting is my kneejerk...i usually go to gedit to strip the crap the re copy and re paste

Comment: If I copy selected text once the clipboard is usually 4 random characters, if I copy twice quickly it is usually fine.  The last time I saw this behaviour it was a bug in klipper (after stopping it, the problem went away)  When the copy works, the text is fine, no funny characters.

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should report the issue to the TightVNC developers so that they can fix the issue:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

http://www.tightvnc.com/bugs.php